# What is an opaque object in the context of the copy module?

Tags: python

Reading the documentation of the python standard library [copy module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) I stumbled across the following sentence:

> The memo dictionary should be treated as an opaque object.

I understand that an opaque object usually is an object whose internals are unknown and which is only accessed via member functions.
What does being an opaque object mean for a simple data structure like a dictionary? And what do I have to pay attention to in the case of implementing `__deepcopy__()` for custom classes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the sentence that precedes your quoted sentence.

> If the `__deepcopy__()` implementation needs to make a deep copy of a component, it should call the deepcopy() function with the component as first argument and the memo dictionary as second argument.

The idea is that your `__deepcopy__` method should do nothing with a received memo dictionary *except* pass it to another call to `deepcopy`. Specifially, you should not

1. Add any keys
2. Remove any keys
3. Modify the value of an existing key.

As far as you are concerned, the memo dictionary *is* an object whose internals are unknown (someday, it may not even *be* a `dict`!). Your only job is to pass it to any "recursive" calls to `deepcopy`.